# LinkedIn Insights tag not injecting properly on my WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api, elementor

I use WordPress for my website and want to ensure that my LinkedIn insights tag displays properly.
I have an issue whereby no matter what method I use (various WP HTML Snippets plugins) only a small portion of my LinkedIn insights tag is displayed on my site.

The insights tag looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_linkedin_partner_id = "123456";
window._linkedin_data_partner_ids = window._linkedin_data_partner_ids || [];
window._linkedin_data_partner_ids.push(_linkedin_partner_id);
</script><script type="text/javascript">
(function(){var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
var b = document.createElement("script");
b.type = "text/javascript";b.async = true;
b.src = "https://snap.licdn.com/li.lms-analytics/insight.min.js";
s.parentNode.insertBefore(b, s);})();
</script>
<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://px.ads.linkedin.com/collect/?pid=123456&fmt=gif" />
</noscript>
```

No matter the method I use, what actually gets injected is only the following portion:

```
<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://px.ads.linkedin.com/collect/?pid=123456&fmt=gif" />
</noscript>
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how to fix it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Translate there are many plugins and as it is probably your theme or plugin are only accepting html.

My suggestion is to open your example theme: **wp-content/themes/{seutema}/header.php**

In this file you can add inside the body tag anywhere. That way it's 100% sure that your code will render normally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>

    <!--- ... other codes --->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    _linkedin_partner_id = "123456";
    window._linkedin_data_partner_ids = window._linkedin_data_partner_ids || [];
    window._linkedin_data_partner_ids.push(_linkedin_partner_id);
    </script><script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    var b = document.createElement("script");
    b.type = "text/javascript";b.async = true;
    b.src = "https://snap.licdn.com/li.lms-analytics/insight.min.js";
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(b, s);})();
    </script>
    <noscript>
    <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://px.ads.linkedin.com/collect/?pid=123456&fmt=gif" />
    </noscript>

</head>
<body>
```

Another option is to add this to the end of your footer.php file within your current theme before closing the body tag.
Example

```
        <!--- ... other codes --->

        <script type="text/javascript">
        _linkedin_partner_id = "123456";
        window._linkedin_data_partner_ids = window._linkedin_data_partner_ids || [];
        window._linkedin_data_partner_ids.push(_linkedin_partner_id);
        </script><script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        var b = document.createElement("script");
        b.type = "text/javascript";b.async = true;
        b.src = "https://snap.licdn.com/li.lms-analytics/insight.min.js";
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(b, s);})();
        </script>
        <noscript>
        <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://px.ads.linkedin.com/collect/?pid=123456&fmt=gif" />
        </noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

**A third option**

You can add this code to your functions.php what may be occurring is that the theme is calling some other file in place of the default.

```
function add_custom_script_footer(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        _linkedin_partner_id = "123456";
        window._linkedin_data_partner_ids = window._linkedin_data_partner_ids || [];
        window._linkedin_data_partner_ids.push(_linkedin_partner_id);
        </script><script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        var b = document.createElement("script");
        b.type = "text/javascript";b.async = true;
        b.src = "https://snap.licdn.com/li.lms-analytics/insight.min.js";
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(b, s);})();
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://px.ads.linkedin.com/collect/?pid=123456&fmt=gif" />
    </noscript>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_custom_script_footer', 9999, 1 );
```

Comment: I've done exactly what you've explained but unfortunately the issue continues to persist.  There must be something filtering out the Javascript.

Comment: Did you put it directly on your theme? Remember that it should be the theme that is enabled and not any of the folder. Which theme are you using? Is the header made by some other plugin?

Comment: I'm using the consulting theme so I've edited /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/wp-content/themes/consulting/footer.php.  I've pasted the insight tag code between two lines:  <?php wp_footer(); ?> above and </body> below.  I've also disabled the snippet so I now get the same result as before.

Comment: Just to make sure the code you entered or if you put a "hello world" is it displaying? it sounds silly but it may be that some other file is being called in the default location.

Comment: Yes, I've tested that successfully.  It's definitely the correct file I've modified.  The extra test text I've added is displaying.

Comment: Ok, updating by adding or code by action, if that doesn't work please enter a URL you are trying to use so that I can check if there is any html structuring problem that is breaking your code. Second option: Try disabling sample and cache plugins that may change the page's html and may be responsible for this issue.

Comment: A fourth option is to add this script just the script directly to some .js file and calling it that way nothing will remove it and if there is any conflict the js log will point to you.

Comment: I found a plugin (AutoOptimise) which had a setting to optimise inline javascript.  I disabled that and it fixed the issue.  Many thanks for your suggestions and apologies, I didn't mean to waste your time!